# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 Breaks All Visual Studio Installations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, failed-installation

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, but it failed during installation. This somehow broke Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and it kept crashing every time I opened it. I decided to uninstall and reinstall VS2013, but the installation keeps failing.

Installation keeps giving a very generic error message:
[image]

(In case the link dies, the error message is: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop - ENU Fatal error during installation.)

Hope the log file helps:
[VS 2013 Log File](http://filebin.ca/1TooUN4Iclo5)

Tried to Google some answers regarding Update 2, but nothing was applicable to my problem.

EDIT: VS 2008 and 2010 installed successfully and now only VS 2012 and 2013 are giving me problems. In the mean time I will use 2010's C# until I can use a more recent version of VS.

Here is 2012's error message:

[image]

VS 2012's log file:
[VS 2012 Log File](http://filebin.ca/1U4Cemopa7De)

I believe there are remnants of VS in my registry somewhere that keeps making any VS installation fail. Can anybody help me? I really need to install VS but I don't want to resort to formatting my computer just to use it, and manually deleting every entry in the registry that pertains to VS would be too tedious, not to mention risky.

Comment: Microsoft recommends to instal them in order, i.e. 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013. Rebuild your box. Work of VM. Make a snapshot, install. If fail - revert.

Comment: Try running the installers of all of the 2013 products with the `/uninstall /force /forcerestart` option to force Visual Studio to remove everything. so: `vs_premium.exe /uninstall /force /forcerestart` for example, then `wdexpress /uninstall etc...` . Reboot after every uninstall. Also open the Programs and Features window in the control panel and from "Installed Updates and Hotfixes" remove any Visual Studio Update 1, Update 2 etc. Then reinstall in order